# Center content without a wrapper

Tags: html, css

How do you center this without a wrapper?

I am able to achieve this with a wrapper.. http://jsfiddle.net/PEp7M/

But I want to be able to do it without one.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
                <h1>LogoHere.com</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
 <a>Something</a>
 <a>Something</a>
 <a>Something</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    color:white;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:black;
}
h1 {
    display:inline;
}
.logo {
    float:left;
}
.nav {
    float:right;
}
```

i just want to not use .header_wrapper as in the fiddle mentiond abov

Comment: May I know the reason behind not using a wrapper element?

Comment: But you do have a wrapper - the `.header`. Or do you want to do without that one? In that case, you do have a wrapper too - the `body`! You can style the body all you like (text align, auto margins etc.)

Comment: "_How do you center this without wrapper?_" What is `this` here?

Comment: You can add `margin` or `padding` to `logo` and `nav`. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PEp7M/5/)

Comment: Is this what you want? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/PEp7M/6/).

Comment: @Mr_Green that does work, but it essentially isn't seperating the nav and logo

Comment: @TrevorMartin if you want to separate more then give more margin to the `.nav`.. :/ do you want me to do that for you or what? or you new to css?

Comment: @Mr.Alien because it is too repetitive and redundant

Comment: @TrevorMartin than you are thinking wrong

Comment: @Mr_Green yea i would probably accept that , i just want to avoid fixed measurements

Comment: @TrevorMartin In css, you can give fix values or percentage values.. Now I have given `margin-left` a percentage value in the `.nav` class. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/PEp7M/7/).

Comment: @Mr_Green perfect i will accpet that

Comment: The person who upvoted for *repetitive and redundant* is also thinking wrong..

Comment: @Mr_Green perfect i will accpet that jquer is good too

Comment: @Mr.Alien I am sure he/she upvoted your above comment too.. hehe.\

Comment: This question is just asking for code without explaining further what has been tried so far. Also the "without wrapping element" is imprecise because the HTML given in the question still has a wrapping element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with `.header` wrapper was working because it was also wrapping the floating elements inside. Once the wrapper is removed then the floating elements can't be tamed using centering methods like `magin: 0 auto` or `text-align: center`. and also the floating property to the `h1` element was hiding the default margin and padding of it. So, go through the following steps:

- Remove `float` property from those child elements.
- Give `display: inline-block` to those child elements.
- Give parent element `text-align: center`. (Here you can't use margin:0 auto because it is meant to use on some element like wrapper, `.header` element, which you have removed.)
- The two child elements are sticking together in one line and are in center now. But to give some gap between them use `margin` css property to left and right of both the child elements in percentages.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/PEp7M/11)

Comment: `.header` is a wrapping element, god knows why [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019570/center-content-without-a-wrapper?noredirect=1#comment28102914_19019570) wants to reinvent the wheel

Comment: best answer thanks for much help my boss impressed

Comment: @Mr.Alien for the dom 3 times

Comment: @TrevorMartin That doesn't even make sense..

Comment: @TrevorMartin Learn a bit more about DOM and CSS, you will get my point and am with JoshC over here.. p.s no offence to the answer, it is good

Comment: @Mr.Alien it works because its in layers i know c+ so it must be working at an example of it

Comment: @TrevorMartin First of all, DOM != CSS, also DOM + CSS !== C++

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm just surprised this guy has a boss. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019570/center-content-without-a-wrapper?noredirect=1#comment28103264_19020024

Comment: @JoshC LOL Yeah I read that, also, I don't know from where he got C++ comparison with the DOM :D

Comment: guys please stop chatting here please.. no offense but just I am getting red alert above in my inbox. I appreciate if you do so... :) [link](http://i.imgur.com/mdjFzlN.jpg)

Comment: I'd say the answer is wrong. First of all it does not put on topic that there still is a wrapper. Second it does the wrong formatting (just a 50%/50% distribution and inside then centered, not the whole, centered). -1 literally because the question itself is of minor quality so the answer can't be better. Voted to delete this crap question that is just asking for code.

Comment: @hakre it does whole center man.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/PEp7M/7/show/). or I just not understood what you are saying..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0CmdC.png

Comment: @hakre yeah you are right... I updated my post. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/PEp7M/11).

Comment: just nit-picking: `.header_wrapper {` does not compute there as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd you like to have the content within the header kept within a centered area, you can add left and right padding to the header element.

http://jsfiddle.net/PEp7M/4/

### HTML

```
<div class="header">

    <div class="logo">
        <h1>LogoHere.com</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <a>Something</a>
        <a>Something</a>
        <a>Something</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    color:white;
}
.header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:black;
    padding: 0 20%;
}

h1 {
    display:inline;
}
.logo {
    float:left;
}
.nav {
    float:right;
}
```

I think wrapper elements make more sense, though.  If you're concerned about writing the same code over and over again (for, say, `.header-wrapper`, `.content-wrapper`, `.footer-wrapper`, etc) just make a reusable class that adds the same amount of padding to them all.

Comment: 1+ That does exactly what the OP wants.. if I understand the OP..

Comment: That's great, but is there a way to do this without percentages/padding

Comment: @TrevorMartin No percentages and no padding? Why? And what other restrictions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Without out wrapper means, you have to use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

however, I'm not sure that your wrapper class does this

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question..

Comment: @JoshC As per my understanding OP tried to center the contents.  So OP can use any of these css style.  Please correct me if I meant wrong.

Comment: i would downvote this is i cuould

Comment: @TrevorMartin I'm open to get downvote.  It would be great if you could provide a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/PEp7M/2/)**. Done the following css correction

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    }
.logo {
   display:inline;
    }
.nav {
    display:inline;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">

    <div class="logo">
        <h1>LogoHere.com</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#">Something</a>
        <a href="#">Something</a>
        <a href="#">Something</a>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Withe text link http://jsfiddle.net/PEp7M/3/

Comment: in my browser, neither of your two fiddles is actually centered.

Comment: and you're still using the wrapper in both fiddles.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a table there?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MqBfn/)**

```
<div class="header">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="logo">
                <h1>LogoHere.com</h1>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="nav">
               <a>Something</a>
               <a>Something</a>
               <a>Something</a>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `table` should be used for layout, instead they should be used to display tabular data.

Comment: that works, but u are chaging the dom.

Comment: Right; a table is not needed nor wanted here. Also, you're using obsolete attributes. And, face it, you're using it as a wrapper, which is what the OP was trying to avoid.